# Delete script-tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create some charts with Highcharts in a cms-system.

I am only allowed to put HTML and Javascripts in a small "box". Here I include Jquery and Highcharts library. And my own scripts.

My problem is that the cms-system includes another Jquery library at the end of the site (after my "box").

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
$(function () {

$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=us-population-density.json&callback=?', function (data) {
    $.each(data, function () {
        this.code = this.code.toUpperCase();
    });
 [...]

 == MY PART ENDS ==
[...]
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

This code wracks my charts (when Jquery loads twice) and I want to find a quick-and-dirty solution to stop the browser from loading the second Jquery file.

Such as:

```
<script>
script = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
for(i = 0;i < script.length; i++)
{
   if (script[i].src == "jquery/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js")
   document.getElementsByTagName('script')[i] = "";
}
</script>
```

But this wouldn't work as the script-tag is after "my part" in the cms.

Do you have any solution?

Comment: Maybe this is the solution: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to play around with jQuery.noConflict(true) that is intented to prevent conflicts between different versions or libraries, read more at [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/). And [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkqgo460/) which demonstrates that using the $ refers to the first loaded version of jquery

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.noConflict demo</title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="log">
  <h3>Before $.noConflict(true)</h3>
</div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>

<script>
var $log = $( "#log" );

$log.append( "2nd loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery + "<br>" );

// Restore globally scoped jQuery variables to the first version loaded
// (the newer version)

jq162 = jQuery.noConflict( true );

$log.append( "<h3>After $.noConflict(true)</h3>" );
$log.append( "1st loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery + "<br>" );
$log.append( "2nd loaded jQuery version (jq162): " + jq162.fn.jquery + "<br>" );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I love Stackoverflow!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Just removing the script tag will not clear the memory, whatever was executed within that script tag stays, even after you remove it.

Did you try holding on to the first jQuery, for instance, by renaming your '$' or calling your wrapped function with argument like ($)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know can you modify the script tags but you can use selectors. For example ;

```
<script id="jquery1" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Then you can remove it with id selector like that $("#jquery1").remove();
That's it if there is no misunderstood

Comment: Unfortunately I can't add an id to the script tag. :(

Comment: Well, don't worry about it. Use selectors again like that : $("script[src='jquery/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js']").remove();